# How to associate arbitrary data with object in Java

Tags: java, android, oop

I'm using [naga](http://code.google.com/p/naga/) to do some asynchronous socket programming.

However I need to be able to attach arbitrary data to the Socket objects.

For instance I have code like so:

```
service = new NIOService();
// Server is JSONObject
NIOSocket socket = service.openSocket(Server.getString("ip"), Server.getInt("port"));
??? Add mydata to socket
socket.listen(observer); // See class below
System.out.println(socket.mydata);// get new data


public static class Observer extends SocketObserverAdapter {

        //Called when Socket makes connection
        @Override
        public void connectionOpened(NIOSocket socket) {
            System.out.println(socket.mydata); // get data
            socket.mydata = "yay!";// set data
        }
}
```

The problem I have is that I need to both get and set data on a socket object in the `Observer.connectionOpened` callback, and be able to access it later.

I realize that there probably isn't a way to just add data to the object, but what's the best way to associate data with the object so that I can pass it around and still access (and modify) the data?

I can always recompile the class code to add the variables to the class, but that seems very hackish, which I try to stay away from.

Note: I'm fairly new to Java programming, but not to programming in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two approaches that come to mind are:

Wrap the Socket in a class that carries information around

```
class MySocketWithData {
    private final Socket theSocket;
    private String myData;
    ....
}
```

or, Maintain a `Map` that holds the information you care about.

```
private final Map<Socket, MyCoolData> socketMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
public void doSomething(Socket sock) {
    MyCoolData data = socketMap.get(sock);
}
```

I'd probably prefer the first.  The second would be more appropriate if you need to hand `Socket` instances around themselves and can't substitute your own class.

Comment: Unforunately, I have to pass the object around, but the second option will work great. Is there any advantage to using Map vs say HashMap? (I realize HashMap is like a subclass or sorts... Is one more efficient?)

Comment: `Map` is the interface, `HashMap` is the implementation.  There are other implementations like `TreeMap` but most of them likely won't be appropriate for `Socket`s.